# Access violation writing location with openSceneGraph

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exception, openscenegraph

Im setting up oculus rift with openSceneGraph(osgOculusViewer) but, the program stop work in this line: viewer.apply(oculusViewConfig).
When i run the debug the error message is: "Unhandled exception at 0x00007ffc20cd8030 (ot13-OpenThreadsd.dll) in OsgOculusViewer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000cdcd0010."
Dont know what is the problem, if i coment this line the viewer oppen and shows the model.
My current directory is the desktop, can that be a problem? Can be some defenitions of the visual studio?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may validate viewer and oculusViewConfig objects. I suppose you must be invoking some functions over viewer object to render, most likely viewer object may not be problem.